# How can i get the dataType when Array is castet into an ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, type-conversion, arraybuffer

I have an Array:

```
var dataArray = new Uint16Array(256);
```

then my array goes over nodeJs to an other pc. (nodejs binaryType = "arraybuffer")

How do I know on the other client that i have to cast to Uint16Array and not Uint8Array?

Note: the bit depth and array length is a dynamic value and can change while programm is running.

Thanks :)

Comment: ok thanks. so i have to transfer this information with every arrayBuffer. Do you know a smart way to attach these information?

Comment: Combined my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When transferring data as `ArrayBuffer` its just binary buffer data, you need to know with what view you want to access the data with. `TypedArrays` are just a view on a binary `ArrayBuffer`.

There are several ways to handle this:

- Use different routes to submit your data
- Add a prefix byte to your data
- And possibly the best solution, do not change your data type mid application.
  imho a clean interface should only handle one type of data.

Comment: Ok thanks. But i have audio data and use different sample and bit rates. can i add a prefix byte without creating a new array ?

Comment: Whats the problem with using different routes? `TypedArray`s are not resizable, you would need to copy its data into another `ArrayBuffer` with a one byte offset.

Comment: what do you exactly mean with routes ? I have only on nodeJs server and only one send and one resive function. How could a make more than this one route ?

Comment: Well i assume you have some kind of webserver running like express/connect. `Routes` are the accessable URLs on your server, or API endpoints in your case. So you would have something like `/audio/8it` and `/audio/16bit` and send requests to the appropriate route. On what routes are and how to define them take a look at the corresponding documentation.

Comment: no thats not working for me. This is a html/Javscript application. Webserver is only needed for downloading the html and js files. Then i have just a client side application with nodeJs Websocket connection. but thanks a lot for your help :) I will try the prefix byte.

Comment: No one says you cant have several routes/endpoints for your websockets ;)